# swift how to use enum in extension

Tags: swift, enums, calayer

how to add some type of CAMediaTimingFunction in CALayer  with extension

```
extension CALayer{
        enum easings {
           case easeIn01
           case easeOut01
        }


        var ease: easings{
           switch self.ease {
           case .easeIn01:
             return (CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715))
           case .easeOut01:
              return (CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1))
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add more information what you trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to access this list in UIView classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to create "shortcut" to your constant timing functions.

```swift
extension CALayer {
    enum Easings {
        case easeIn01
        case easeOut01

        var timing: CAMediaTimingFunction {
            switch self {
            case .easeIn01:
                return CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715)
            case .easeOut01:
                return CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1)
            }
        }
    }
}

/// To get easing
CALayer.Easings.easeIn01

/// To get timing function
CALayer.Easings.easeIn01.timing
```